# How to get current day using the CASE statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have to write a program using the CASE statement, which for each separate day of the week will be able to return the name of the day, and by executing, it will return the name of the current day. How do I do it?

Comment: Why not just use `datename()`?

Comment: Because it's homework and I have to do it like that

Comment: Try something using a `case` _expression_ and add it to your question. We'll help you with a specific problem, but not write the code for you.

Answer (score 1):

**I think this is correct**

```
SELECT CASE (SELECT DATENAME(dw, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
WHEN N'Monday' THEN N'Its Monday'
WHEN N'Tuesday' THEN N'Its Tuesday'
WHEN N'Wednesday' THEN N'Its Wednesday'
WHEN N'Thursday' THEN N'Its Thursday'
WHEN N'Friday' THEN N'Its Friday'
WHEN N'Saturday' THEN N'Its Saturday'
WHEN N'Sunday' THEN N'Its Sunday'
END;
```

Comment: For a numeric alternative `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, Current_Timestamp ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`. That avoids your code choking on "Martes" when used with the language set to Spanish. (An `else` clause could catch it and return the input as part of a fallback result.)

Comment: You don't need the second `select`, you can simply use `SELECT CASE DATENAME(dw, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) WHEN ...`. And spelling out the date part, e.g. `weekday` instead of `dw`, makes maintenance easier. Pop quiz: Is `m` month or minute? 'month' and 'minute' are obvious.